# UIScrollView subview bring to centre when zoomed

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I am making a map like screen where inside a scroll view is a map image much bigger than the scroll view. Now when a user taps on a location on the table beside the map, the user is taken to the location point and the location is brought to centre. I am using this code to plot the marker and bring the marker to centre:

```
CGRect frame=CGRectMake(pt.x - roundf(scrollMap.frame.size.width/2.0),
                        pt.y - roundf(scrollMap.frame.size.height/2.0),
                        scrollMap.frame.size.width, scrollMap.frame.size.height);

[scrollMap scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

This is working absolutely fine. But this doesn't work when the Map is zoomed in or zoomed out. I have tried every possible way to use the zoomscale of the scrollview to make this happen but in vain. I think i am missing something. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a sample I have made [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptewhwo2ccvmp5q/Zoomer.zip)

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Found this fantastic one line code which did the job...just that it scales the scrollview to max scroll...

```
[scrollMap zoomToRect:marker.frame animated:YES];
```

Thanks.